# babel shows object spread operator unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const a = {"abc": 123};
const b = {
  ...a,
  "hello": "world"
}
```

What's wrong with this syntax? tried it in babelio got unexpected token.

Comment: Try this "npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0" and then 

//.babelrc
{
  "presets": ["stage-0"]
}

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Answer (score 2):

The default babel env config does not handle spread operator

You need [@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread.html)